# Android: Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: android, class, android-studio

I have trouble running my application. It just happened suddenly. One moment i could run my app, the next one i couldn't.. It's giving me the exception:

```
11-08 19:04:42.936  20390-20390/dk.chargesmart.findstroem E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{dk.chargesmart.findstroem/dk.chargesmart.findstroem.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException
```

And in the android manifest file it says that my activity is not public

[image]

Here the "head" of the activity

```
class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap mMap;
ClusterManager<MyPin> mClusterManager;
ArrayList<Location> mLocations;
boolean showDetail;
boolean menuHidden;
boolean isAnimating;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    downloadItems();

    menuHidden = false;

    setUpMenu();
}
```

Here is more about the exception

```
11-08 19:04:42.936  20390-20390/dk.chargesmart.findstroem E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{dk.chargesmart.findstroem/dk.chargesmart.findstroem.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You activity should be defined as

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Keyword is **public**.

Comment: Doh, i deserve a facepalm for this one - coding with hangover :b thanks a lot. So much time wasted for something so simple.

Comment: Somes it happens when switching from other jvm languages (such as: groovy) to java, because classes are public by default in most of them.